# Manually starting a workflow 2010 created in sharepoint designer 2013 return infopath error

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, sharepoint-2016, workflow-manager-1.x

I've created a simple workflow 2010 in SharePoint Designer 2013 with admin user that should be manually triggered from a user in a SharePoint 2016 intranet.
The problem is that if I trigger the WF associated to the doc lib, logged in with the admin user, it succesfully start. But for any other user it return this error related to the infopath form
[Infopath error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cioam.png)

I just tried to:

- Create the WF with another user
- Change the compatibility option in infopath designer but it is disabled
- Clear the sharepoint designer 2013 cache
- Create a reusable 2010 WF and then associate it to the list